# Discord Bot isn't responding to command

Tags: python, discord

My discord bot is not responding to "test". There are no error messages, so I am very confused why this is happening.

I just started Python today and I wanted to learn how to make a Discord bot

```
    import discord

    client = discord.Client(intents = discord.Intents.default())

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        general_channel = client.get_channel(1045161050024185899)

        await general_channel.send('Bot Activated By-**GotYoHat** \nMade By **GotYoHat** using **Python**')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.content == 'test':
            await message.channel.send('work')

    client.run('the token is right here')
```

I searched the internet for an answer and I can't find a single answer online

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on intents.
Try to discord.Intents.all()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).